# Rails migration join table for multiple associations of the same model using different names

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my project, I have this simple association set up:

```
class Episode < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :game_master, :class_name => 'CastMember'
  has_and_belongs_to_many :players, :class_name => 'CastMember'
end

class CastMember < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :episodes
end
```

I was wondering what the join table for these might be.

At first, I thought a `cast_members_episodes` table would be enough, but after thinking about it for a bit, it wouldn't make sense, as it wouldn't be able to differentiate between `game_master` and `players`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `cast_members_episodes` table to handle the many-to-many relation of `players` and `episodes`.

And, add a column `game_master_id` to `episodes` table to handle the relation of `game_master` and `episodes`.

Comment: Welp, yeah, makes sense! Thanks! I guess a `t.belongs_to :game_master, index: true` on `Episode` would also work!